# Remotely display a message on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I've got a Motorola MC9590 with Windows Mobile 6.5. It is connected to the company's Wi-Fi.

The task is simple: Send a text message from another computer in the same network and display it on the screen.

I have already tried using msg.exe with no luck.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy (built-in) way to remotely display a message on a Windows Mobile 6.x device. Such feature is normally provided by a Mobile Device Management System, like SOTI MobiControl or Honeywell's SmartSystem Console.

Showing a message on a remote Windows Mobile device needs an Agent or Server software running on the device that listens for messages to display and a Network client software that sends the Message content via network to the listening Server/Agent.